# How to rotate an image in java about a specific point rather than the image centre?

Tags: java, image, rotation, graphics2d

I've so far been using the

```
Graphics2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(-1), newImage.getWidth() / 2, newImage.getHeight() / 2);
```

to rotate an image for an OMR Application. The result is a rotated but blurred image. Also I doubt this rotates the image about its centre. How do i specify a specific pixel-position as the centre of rotation?

Comment: The second parameters are the x/y position to rotate about.  Personally, I use an `AffineTransformation` instead, something line [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884480/rotate-an-image-in-java-by-the-specified-angle/14885645#14885645) for example

Answer (score 2):

> I doubt this rotates the image about its centre

You're correct, you would need

```
g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(-1), (newImage.getWidth() / 2) + 1, (newImage.getHeight() / 2) + 1);
```

Because of the fact, that co-ordinates start at the top left-hand corner location `0, 0`, (rather than `1, 1`), you need to add `1` to each of the divided widths to get the center.

> How do i specify a specific pixel-position as the centre of rotation?

As @MadProgrammer said in his comment, the *x* and *y* parameters are the 2nd and 3rd arguments in [rotate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double,%20double,%20double%29), so these are the pixel positions in relation to the `Image`.

Comment: Could u pls tell what's the significance of adding 1 here? How do i specify the pixel position, say (p,q)?